# Selenium - Cannot find DOM Element

Tags: java, selenium

I have a login page, After the user logs in I want to find DOM elements how can I pipeline the output of the login page to another .java file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to tell exactly what you mean, but you can do:

```
String allHtml = driver.getPageSource();

OtherJavaFile otherJavaFile = new OtherJavaFile(allHtml);
```

this of course means that the constructor of OtherJavaFile is a String.